# Подключение dll в Maven проект. Jacob

Tags: java, maven

Перевожу проект на maven и столкнулся со следующей проблемой:
Есть такая библиотека - `jacob`. И у нее кроме jar есть 2 dll. Раньше я ее просто прикладывал в корневую папку и jar работал корректно. Но **при переходе на maven он их перестал видеть.**

```
java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: no jacob-1.18-x64 in java.library.path
```

Провел кучу экспериментов с размещением dll и настройки переменной `java.library.path` и парочку с плагином `maven-surefire-plugin`.

Comment: а если их просто в `target/...` добавить работать корректно будет?

Comment: Нет. Пробовал и при компиляции из IDE и после руками запускать - все едино.

Comment: maven - это только средство сборки. Если при добавлении в итоговую сборку. проект не работает, то дело не в maven-е

Comment: Вот что нарыл, должно решить вашу проблему. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1001774/managing-dll-dependencies-with-maven

Comment: @FORTRAN, я так понимаю, что добавление руками в итоговую сборку, не помогает запустить проект. Как должен помочь вывод dll файлов в зависимости?

Comment: @Tachkin вы подозревайте что эти dll файлы некорректные?

Comment: @FORTRAN, либо так, либо структура проекта предполагает другой classpath, относительно jar библиотеки, использующей данные dll библиотеки. Т.е. сначала посмотреть в какое место итоговой сборки проекта надо эти dll добавить, что бы проект корректно работал, а потом уже плагины настраивать.

Answer (score 1):

Увы, все оказалось банальнее. Толи что-то было с именем dll толи они были повреждены. Перекачал - все заработало.

Answer (score 0):

Вот что нарыл, должно решить вашу проблему. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1001774/managing-dll-dependencies-with-maven

Если нет, возможно поможет написать ваш вопрос на англ. или я тоже попробую так как вопрос довольно таки может пригодится для многих.